# c setvbuf() function call not working as expected

Tags: c

I'm learning system programming and when I run the following code

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char buff[5];
    setvbuf(stderr, buff, _IOFBF, 5);
    for (int i = 1; i < 10; i++) {
        fprintf(stderr, "%d", i);
    }
    _exit(0);
}
```

`setvbuf` is imposing fully buffered policy on `stderr` with a 5-byte sized buffer, so I expected to get `12345` but instead it prints `1234567`, why is that?

Comment: @JeffHolt hi Jeff would you mind checking the updated question? thx!

Comment: What OS is this on? Neither `fprintf` nor `setvbuf` are system calls in any OS that I'm aware of.

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Hi Joe you're right it's part of the standard library not system, just removed the system call tag thanks!

Comment: If it is any help, testing on a MacBook Pro running macOS Mojave 10.14.6 with GCC 9.2.0, I get your expected output — `12345` and my command line prompt follows immediately afterwards because there was no newline.  Or, in other words, I cannot reproduce.  You may need to identify your o/s and version, and perhaps th compiler and library versions.  (Also, when I changed the lower bound of the loop from 1 to 0, I got `01234` and not `0123456789` which might have been possible.)

Comment: @JonathanLeffler hi John I'm running ubuntu not sure whether it's os related but you can check the online ide https://repl.it/repls/StylishHarmfulGlobalarrays which produces same output in my question.

Comment: I can reproduce what you're seeing on Ubuntu.  I think the short answer is "treat setvbuf as advisory" - don't assume it will always buffer just the way you want.  If you want to absolutely ensure that writes are buffered, do your own buffering.  For the gory details as to exactly what Linux libc does, you have to read the glibc source code.  I tried a little bit and can see where it does what it does, but don't really understand why.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

strace-ing the program shows that when compiled against glibc it first does a write of size 1, then a write of size 5, and finally a write of size 1:

```
$ strace -o /dev/stdout -e write,writev ./a.out 2>/dev/null
write(2, "1", 1)                        = 1
write(2, "23456", 5)                    = 5
write(2, "7", 1)                        = 1
```

With musl it does 7 writes of size 1:

```
$ strace -o /dev/stdout -e write,writev ./a.out 2>/dev/null
writev(2, [{iov_base="1", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="2", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="3", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="4", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="5", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="6", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="7", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="8", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
writev(2, [{iov_base="9", iov_len=1}, {iov_base=NULL, iov_len=0}], 2) = 1
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

So it's obvious that both C library implementations treat the `size` argument of `setvbuf(stream, buf, _IOFBF, size)` as a maximum, and they feel free to flush the buffer even before it's full.

AFAICS there doesn't seem to be anything in the standard against this interpretation.

Comment: Indeed, C17 7.21.3 (3), emphasis mine: "When a stream is fully buffered, characters are **intended** to be transmitted to or from the host environment as a block when a buffer is filled. [...] Support for these characteristics is implementation-defined [...]"